# Specific domain computer login when integrating with Windows domain

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, active-directory

I'm trying to let a user named "linuxuser" can only login to a specific domain computer.
My test environment description:

1. Windows Server 2016 with Active Directory Service
2. Ubuntu Server 20.04.4 (Hostname: SMBWINBIND)

My expected behavior is user "linuxuser" can only login to SMBWIND (Can't login to any other domain computers).

Ways i have already tried:

- sssd + realmd
- krb5

In this two ways, i can success login to SMBWIND, the problem is if i set linuxuser can only login another domain computer, i find linuxuser still can login to SMBWIND.

Is there a way can make "user log on to" feature (see image at bottom) in Windows Active Directory works normal on Linux?
[image]